# READ from VSAM file using CICS

Tags: cics, vsam

How can I read from a VSAM  file continuously?
I have a VSAM file contining some records. I need to read records one by using CICS commands, but I dont know where the file ends.Is there any way to signal that the file has reached the end to stop the reading process.

I tried ´EXEC CICS READNEXT

Comment: What were your results when trying EXEC CICS READNEXT?

Comment: I didnt know how to use it?

Comment: I got error number 16 or INVREC.

Answer (score 1):

You browse through a file using STARTBR followed by multiple READNEXT commands and then an ENDBR command. You repeat the READNEXT command to read all the records in the file and when the end of the file is reached the READNEXT command fails with an ENDFILE response. You then issue end ENDBR.

Comment: STARTBR is used to specify where the record browsing to start in a file. How can we made it to start browsing from the first record, or any particular record that we want?

Comment: I tried the above process, but unfortunately, STARTBR encountered error number16 or INVREQ which means ´INVREQ – Read operation not permitted as it is not mentioned in the FCT. Record is locked´ but I dont know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Soraya, there are several reasons why you might receive an error response of 16 (INVREQ). If you specify RESP2(field-name) in your STARTBR command, you will receive a value indicating the reason for the INVREQ response.  If you do not code the RESP2 operand on your STARTBR command, you can also access this RESP2 value in the EIBRESP2 field.